# How to integrate CkFinder in drupal 8

Tags: 8, installation, wysiwyg

I am struggling in the integration of `CKFinder` to `CKEditor` in a development `drupal 8` installation.

Where to place the folder and how to tell the Editor to use `CKFinder`

Comment: I found this response on Drupal.org today. https://www.drupal.org/node/2545404
The explanation seems accurate.

Comment: IMCE File Manager module is available for D8. https://www.drupal.org/project/imce. Provides a file manager supporting personal folders.